# Copy content from HTML element and export to text file with Python3.x

Tags: html, python-3.x, copy

I am using a python3.x script to save a string to a text file:

```
nN = "hello"

f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write(nN)
f.close()
```

and now I am trying to parse the content of an h2 element from a website (page scraping works fine) and I am getting an error when I am trying this:

```
nN = driver.find_element_by_id("title")

f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write(nN)
f.close()
```

where the html line is:

```
<h2 id="title">hello</h2>
```

The error is:

**write() argument must be str, not WebElement**

I tried converting the nN into a string using the following:

```
f.write(str(nN))
```

and the new error is:

**invalid syntax**

Comment: How about `f.write(str(nN))`? I'm not sure what a `driver` object is, or what `find_element_by_id()` returns; but as the error states, `f.write()` must have a type `str` as its explicit parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using Selenium and then using the webdriver to parse the html content?

The reason the string conversion is not working is because the `nN` is a Selenium/html object that probably is a dictionary or a list. You could try simply `f.write(nN.text)` and according to the documentation the .text version of nN should work.

To the larger issue of parsing html though, I would recommend using Beautiful Soup. Do `pip3 install BeautifulSoup4` and then to import `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. Then as example:

```
with open('file.html','r') as f:
  htmltext = f # change as necessary, just needs to be string
  soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext,'lxml')
  h2found = soup.find('h2',id="title")
  print(h2found)
  print(h2found.text)
```

Beautiful Soup has [great documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and is the standard and best library to use for parsing html.